# Python - calculate the distance with different data types in python

Tags: python, binary, distance, ordinal

I have a data with the 11 attributes. I want to calculate the distance on each of these attributes. for example its attribute `(x1, x2, ..., x11)` and for `x1` & `x2` has a nominal type, `x3, x4, ... x10` has ordinal type, then `x11` has binary type. how can I read the attributes using python? and how to differentiate these attributes in python and how to differentiate these attributes in python so I can calculate the distance? can someone tell me what should I do? thank you

sample data: x1 (forestry,plantation,other,forestry) x2 (plantation, plantation, shrubs, forest) x3 (high, high, medium, low) x4 (low, medium, high, high) x5 (high, low, medium, high) x6 (medium, low, high, medium) x7 (3, 1, 0, 4) x8 (low, low, high, medium) x9 (297, 298, 299, 297) x10 (1, 2, 0, 4) x11 (t, t, t, f)

Comment: Could you provide some sample data?

Comment: save those values as a list. then you can call the youList[0] is the x1

Comment: this is a sample data:
x1 (forestry,plantation,other,forestry)
x2 (plantation, plantation, shrubs, forest)
x3 (high, high, medium, low)
x4 (low, medium, high, high)
x5 (high, low, medium, high)
x6 (medium, low, high, medium)
x7 (3, 1, 0, 4)
x8 (low, low, high, medium)
x9 (297, 298, 299, 297)
x10 (1, 2, 0, 4)
x11 (t, t, t, f)

Comment: So what is the "distance" between forestry and plantation?

Comment: because x1 & x2 is nominal type, i can calculate distance with d(i,j) = (p-m)/p. p is total number of attribute and m is attributes for i & j are in same state. ex d(1,2) = (2-0)/2 = 1.

Comment: @user3500153 So the distance between ``x1 =(forestry,plantation,other,forestry)`` and ``x2= (plantation, plantation, shrubs, forestry)`` is 2/4=1/2 because they have the same value in there second and last position?

Comment: no like that, for the sample data has 4 rows. ex row 1(forestry, plantation, high, low, high, medium, 3, low, 297, 1, t), row 2(plantation, plantation, high, medium, low, low, 1, low, 298, 2, t).
so d(1,2) is distance between row 1 and 2, but in 1 row has 3 data type(ordinal, nominal, binary) so I had to calculate the distance according to the data type, and then I can calculate the distance by combining the results of the count of 3 types

Comment: @user3500153 See the last update of my answer...

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
def distance(x,y):
    p = len(x)
    m = sum(map(lambda (a,b): 1 if a == b else 0, zip(x,y)))
    return float(p-m)/p
```

Example:

```
x1 = ("forestry", "plantation", "high", "low", "high", "medium", 3, "low", 297, 1, True)
x2 = ("plantation", "plantation", "high", "medium", "low", "low", 1, "low", 298, 2, True)

print distance(x1,x2) # result: 0.636363636364 = (11-4)/7
```

Comment: thanks for your help. but the distance can only be used for forestry and plantation. to value high, low, medium, 3, 297, and other are the type of ordinal,and for true, false are binary type. so that's distance can't use for all data. i must calculate data of ordinal type, binary type, and then i can get distance with mixed types

Comment: for binary type (true, false) we can use this: d(i,j) = (r+s)/(q+r+s+t). r is total of variable with i positive & j negative, s is total of variable with i negative & j postive, q is total variable with i&j postive, t is total variable with i&j negative

Comment: and ordinal type, we must replace each value by its rank (ex. in data low = 1, medium = 2, high =3 and 0 = 1, 1 = 2, 2 = 3, 3 = 4, 4 = 5). then normalize the ranking with zif = (rif-1)/(mf-1). zif represent the value for the ith object, rif rank of data, mf is total data (ex. for low, medium, high. mf = 3). so the last we can use calculate this data with euclidean distance

Comment: Have you already tried something in python? Please post your attempts in your question. And do not forget to give a clear and detailed description how you want to calculate the overall distance between two data tuples (I guess no one will read this comments to get those information...). It would also be good to provide an exmple of two data tuples and the distance you want to have in the end of them.

Comment: I also did not understand, how you want to calculate the distance between two data tuples...

Comment: I have tried but I can't, python is a new programming language I learned. I want to calculate the distance for my final assignment.

Comment: You mean the euclidean distance?

Comment: euclidean distance is the last step for ordinal type

Comment: How do you want combine the three different distances? Euclidean distance? Distance from maximum norm or distance from p-norm? Shall be each calculated distance by type be equally weighted for your final distance?

Comment: I recommend you to try first easier code examples in python. If you have problems with them, you can make a post on this site. Have you already read a good tutorial/book about python? (I mean read in detail with trying and understanding the code examples) You should also ask a friend, whether he can help you (your problem seems to be to complicated for a short answer)

Comment: thanks @tampis for your help. i will try again learning about python. i has read a book about python, but i will read again in detail and tries to understanding the code.

Answer (score 0):

I've rewritten this as follows:

First I create a Nominal type factory:

```
class BaseNominalType:
    name_values = {}   # <= subclass must override this

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.value = self.name_values[name]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def __sub__(self, other):
        assert type(self) == type(other), "Incompatible types, subtraction is undefined"
        return self.value - other.value

# class factory function
def make_nominal_type(name_values):
    try:
        nv = dict(name_values)
    except ValueError:
        nv = {item:i for i,item in enumerate(name_values)}

    # make custom type
    class MyNominalType(BaseNominalType):
        name_values = nv
    return MyNominalType
```

Now I can define your nominal types,

```
Forest = make_nominal_type(["shrubs", "plantation", "forestry", "other"])
Level  = make_nominal_type(["low", "medium", "high"])
Bool   = make_nominal_type({"f":False, "t":True})
```

Then I make a MixedVector type factory:

```
# base class
class BaseMixedVectorType:
    types = []          # <= subclass must
    distance_fn = None  # <=   override these

    def __init__(self, values):
        self.values = [type_(value) for type_,value in zip(self.types, values)]

    def dist(self, other):
        return self.distance_fn([abs(s - o) for s,o in zip(self.values, other.values)])

# class factory function
def make_mixed_vector_type(types, distance_fn):
    tl = list(types)
    df = distance_fn

    class MyVectorType(BaseMixedVectorType):
        types = tl
        distance_fn = df
    return MyVectorType
```

then create your data type,

```
# your mixed-vector type
DataItem = make_mixed_vector_type(
    [Forest, Forest, Level, Level, Level, Level, int, Level, int, int, Bool],
    ??? # have to define an appropriate distance function!
)
```

... but wait, we haven't defined a distance function! I wrote the class to allow you to plug in whatever distance function you like, in the form:

```
def manhattan_dist(_, vector):
    return sum(vector)

def euclidean_dist(_, vector):
    return sum(v*v for v in vector) ** 0.5

# the distance function per your description:
def fractional_match_distance(_, vector):
    return float(sum(not v for v in vector)) / len(vector)
```

so we finish creating

```
# your mixed-vector type
DataItem = make_mixed_vector_type(
    [Forest, Forest, Level, Level, Level, Level, int, Level, int, int, Bool],
    fractional_match_distance
)
```

and test it as

```
def main():
    raw_data = [
        ('forestry', 'plantation', 'high', 'low', 'high', 'medium', 3, 'low', 297, 1, 't'),
        ('plantation', 'plantation', 'high', 'medium', 'low', 'low', 1, 'low', 298, 2, 't'),
        ('other', 'shrubs', 'medium', 'high', 'medium', 'high', 0, 'high', 299, 0, 't'),
        ('forestry', 'forestry', 'low', 'high', 'high', 'medium', 4, 'medium', 297, 4, 'f')
    ]

    a, b, c, d = [DataItem(d) for d in raw_data]

    print("a to b, dist = {}".format(a.dist(b)))
    print("b to c, dist = {}".format(b.dist(c)))
    print("c to d, dist = {}".format(c.dist(d)))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

which gives us

```
a to b, dist = 0.363636363636
b to c, dist = 0.0909090909091
c to d, dist = 0.0909090909091
```